# If $\mu$ and $\nu$, is $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ more a notation or does it make sense?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ two measure. I know that $$\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}=f$$ mean that $$\mu(A)=\int_A fd\nu.\tag{D}$$
But is $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}=f$ is a notation for $(D)$ or does it really has a "variational sense" ?

Comment: You can live a full and rewarding  life if you opt for the first, "(D)" sense.

Comment: Though $f$ is defined through (D) it is interesting to note that $\frac {d\mu} {d\nu} \frac {d\nu} {d\tau}=\frac {d\mu} {\\d\tau}$ as we are dealing with actual ratios!.